# Prevent unauthorized image flashing

Tags: security, rom-flashing, fastboot

I wonder whether there is a way to prevent someone to use `fastboot` to flash an Android device.

Indeed, while one must be able to turn on *USB debug* in order to run `adb`, the bootloader does not offer any protection AFAIK.

Comment: The easiest way to prevent someone to do things like that is to not give that someone physical access to your device. Once having physical access, there isn't really much you can prevent a clever hacker from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may only make `oem lock`, but if anybody really need to flash something - he can do unlock  again (with removing anything from device).

And one old rule: if anybody has physical access to device - software protection will not help.

Comment: I am aware of that, I only make sure it is not possible to lock the stock bootloader down.